# Proper name scrolling news/photo

Tags: web-development, javascript, website-design, content

I'm very new to webdesign and am wanting to install a scrolling news/picture banner in the site but don't even know the proper term to search for to find out how to do it.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

http://www.ed.gov/ and http://www.nysed.gov/

What is this called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Drive calls them [Slide-Shows](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/index.html). There are tons of variations. Slideshow is a common name. It may also be called a *Carousel* if it appears to turn. There is probably no official name if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your open a whole new world to your web designs by searching for "jQuery Examples"

Some links here for you to explore which has jQuery sliders which is basiclly what I see on those links provided.

- http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html
- http://www.templatelite.com/100-popular-jquery-plugins/

Enjoy your new founded world of jQuery... Search for jQuery Isotope you're love that one ;)

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  I didn't know about these.  This is much appreciated.